# Web3js will not compile on Azure

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, compiler-errors, web3js

##### Steps to reproduce:

1. In Visual Studio 2019 Community, create a new Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 Application (TypeScript).
2. Npm install web3
3. Add a line 4 after `import path = require('path');`

   ```
   var Web3 = require('web3');
   ```
4. Run it locally to ensure that it works (it does)
5. Publish it to Azure and watch the logs

##### Expected Result

It should compile and run fine -- just as it did locally in step 4

Actual Results (from Azure log stream)

> Thu Apr 02 2020 17:31:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js:285.then(async function (receipt) {^^^^^SyntaxError: missing ) after argument listat Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)at Module.load (module.js:487:32)at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)at Module.require (module.js:497:17)at require (internal/module.js:20:19)at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\web3-core\src\extend.js:27:14)at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js:285.then(async function (receipt) {^^^^^SyntaxError: missing ) after argument listat Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)at Module.load (module.js:487:32)at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)at Module.require (module.js:497:17)at require (internal/module.js:20:19)at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\web3-core\src\extend.js:27:14)at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

I have looked at line 285 in `\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js` and it looks fine.

I deleted my package-lock.json and my node_modules directory and npm installed again (not to mention that I did it on both the original project *and* the small test project).

I'm at a loss here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be complete, I ran it under WSL2 on my desktop just now and it was fine there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure, by default has an abysmally old version of Node -- and you can only upgrade it to 8.9.4 (while node 12.16.1 is the LTS version).

But upgrading by adding the configuration setting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION with a value of 8.9.4 *will* fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue running the latest version of web3 (1.2.6) with react on my desktop, this error shows on importing web3.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
```

It's interesting to note that there is no issue if I write the same line in node interactive console and the object `Web3` works properly.

I change the web3 version to 1.0.0-beta.55 and it worked fine. I hope that this is a bug to be fixed in the latest versions.

PS: before I tried changing web3 version, I tried updating node from 8.9.4 to 13.12.0 but the error still persisted.